# Rails 4 Reflexive Many-to-Many Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many, rails-activerecord, model-associations

I'm implementing a Rails 4 app that has a Reflexive Many-to-Many Association to represent some MailChimp and HelpScout API parameters.

Some of those parameters have child parameters. Thus, those child parameters have parent parameters (otherwise they couldn't be a child, right?! ;D ).

To implement the reflexive association the two tables below were created

```
create_table "api_params", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "description"
  t.string   "type"
  t.boolean  "required"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "nested_params", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "parent_param_id"
  t.integer  "child_param_id"
  t.boolean  "required"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "nested_params", ["child_param_id"], name: "index_nested_params_on_child_param_id"
add_index "nested_params", ["parent_param_id"], name: "index_nested_params_on_parent_param_id"
```

What I'd like to have are two methods. One to retrieve a database record's parents and another one to retrieve its children. Below I show you an example.

```
apiParam = ApiParam.first # retrieving any database record
apiParam.parent_params
# => returns a set of apiParam's parents
apiParam.child_params
# => returns a set of apiParam's children
```

I read all day long about associations but the examples are always the same. I mean, there is always a class where you define a has_many through and another one where you define a belongs_to but it wasn't enough for what I need.

Thanks in advance. I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: could you explain why `has_many :through` doesn't work? At first glance, it seems like `has_many :children, through: :nested_params`

Comment: @txdavidtx the problem is that I need a relation in both directions so that I'll be able to get parent_params and child_params. Another problem is that I didn't use default names for nested_params table's foreign keys and that's making everything a little bit difficult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and I hope it can be helpful for everyone with same kind of problem.

In short, I've got the answer from Ryan Bates' railscasts.com website. More specificly, the answer were found [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association).

My classes are now as follow:

```
class NestedParam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :api_param
  belongs_to :child_param, class_name: 'ApiParam'
end

class ApiParam < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :nested_params
  has_many :child_params, :through => :nested_params
  has_many :parent_api_params, :class_name => "NestedParam", :foreign_key => "child_param_id"
  has_many :parent_params, :through => :parent_api_params, :source => :api_param
end

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140910175658) do

  create_table "api_params", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "description"
    t.boolean  "required",    default: true
    t.boolean  "struct",      default: false
    t.string   "type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "nested_params", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "api_param_id"
    t.integer  "child_param_id"
    t.boolean  "required"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "nested_params", ["api_param_id"], name: "index_nested_params_on_api_param_id"
  add_index "nested_params", ["child_param_id"], name: "index_nested_params_on_child_param_id"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I have your solution (in my case I have the model SyncType):

```
class SyncType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many(:parents,
    :class_name => "SyncType",
    :join_table => "sync_type_parents",
    :foreign_key => "sync_type_id",
    :association_foreign_key => "sync_type_parent_id")

  has_and_belongs_to_many(:children,
    :class_name => "SyncType",
    :join_table => "sync_type_parents",
    :foreign_key => "sync_type_parent_id",
    :association_foreign_key => "sync_type_id")
end
```

migration:

```
create_table "sync_type_parents", :force => true, :id => false do |t|
  t.integer "sync_type_id", :null => false
  t.integer "sync_type_parent_id", :null => false
end
```

Enjoy! ;)

Comment: Thank you, Diego, but I have a 'required' inside my nested_params table. So, I think it the usage of makes has_and_belongs_to_many impossible, right?

Comment: [http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many)